# Empty Parameter for Python Lambda Function

Tags: python, lambda

Is it possible in python to write a lambda function that does not need any parameters passed to it? For instance, is there a way to translate this function:

```
def file_opener():
    f = open('filename.txt').read()
    return f
```

or any other function with no passed input
into a lambda expression?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You certainly *can* do it..

```
x = lambda : 6
print(x())  # prints -> 6
```

You probably shouldn't though. Once you feel the need to bind a function to a variable name you should go the long road instead (`def ..`) as you do it in your example.

Comment: Once again, lets not keep writing bad examples for `lambda`. They are used to write anonymous functions. Once you assign them to a variable, you should have used `def`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this (Recommended as no hard-coding is present):

```
file = lambda f: open(f).read()

print (file('open.txt'))
```

If you don't want to pass filename as an argument then use this:

```
f = lambda: open('open.txt').read()

print (f())
```

Comment: but you are passing an argument here (`f`).

Comment: you can hard-code it but generally when we are opening a file it's not recommended because your path will always change.

Comment: Sure but that is what OP **explicitly** asked for.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Updated the answer to deal with both the conditions. . Thanks :)

Comment: Assigning a `lambda` to a variable completely invalidates the reason for having lambdas in the first place. `lambda` is used to write anonymous functions. If you want a named function, use `def`. This may just be a toy example but do we really need another example of improper use of lambda?

Comment: @PrakharVerma, so, instead of passing an argument to lambda function as per python syntax, you passed it explicitly. Moreover, under the explicit condition, the lambda function will only run for 1 argument hardcoded in it. Correct me if I am wrong? Also could suggest any particular reason for doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Just try it!

```
>>> open('filename.txt', 'w').write('this is filename.txt contents')
29
>>> def call_this(fctn):
...     return fctn()
... 
>>> print(call_this(lambda: open('filename.txt').read()))
this is filename.txt contents
```

It works